# Setting parameters in jsp and in servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my web application , I get a request from the client. I process the request in my jsp page or the servlet(which ever is called) and want to forward to other jsp's or servlets accordingly.
 But before forwarding I want to set a few parameters and then forward it with these new parameters. The old parameters should not be present when forwarding. Only the new parameters should be present. How can this be done?
Can I forward from a servlet to jsp and vice-versa?
Please tell how the above can be accomplished?

Comment: You've left one very important requirement out your question: you needed to "forward" to a new domain (see comment on Rakesh's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use request dispatcher and redirect as per your need and requirement.

```
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("url");

rd.forward(request,response);
```

or

```
response.sendRedirect("url");
```

sendRedirect() sends the header back to the browser , which contains the name of the resource to be redirected to. So this will be a **new request** to the resource from the browser .

forward() action takes place within the server without the knowledge of the browser .

Answer (score 4):

If you have no use for the request parameters and your jsp/servlet has not written anything to the response, then I suppose it would be fine to use redirect instead of forward, since redirecting will discard the request along with the parameters.

When you do redirect, you can create dynamically and set the querystring like so:

```
response.sendRedirect("url?a=" + var1 +"&b=" + var2);
```

Take note that this will be a GET method to the url. If url will be resolved to a servlet, you can implement the doGet method to just call the doPost.

*Please note that a redirect will be ignored if the jsp/servlet has written something already on the response...*

Answer (score 3):

yes you can forward the parameter servlet to jsp and jsp to servlet.

when you can set the attribute in request then it will lost on destination.means you can not access that on third resource.

```
request.setAttribute(attribute name,attribute value)
```

you can do same thing in session also.

Comment: After finishing processing in a servlet, I want to send a xml strnig to a jsp page. I think only redirect will work because I 've to send it to a new domain. My question is can I send it using Post.

Comment: you need to set the xml data in session because only session is exists in another vertual machine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to forward to JSP/Servlet using RequestDisptcher. Set the request attribute on the request to set parameters using

```
request.setAttribute(name, value)
```

The Forwarded JSP can read the parameter using

```
request.getAttribute(name)
```

But, You `cannot hide the attribute existing before forward by default`. You can achieve this using Request Wrapper. Wrap the request before forwarding override the set and get attribute methods.

**Below code explains**

```
    RequestDisptcher dispatcher =  req.getRequestDispatcher("url");
    HideExistingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = 
                                         new HideExistingRequestWrapper(request);
    requestWrapper.setAtribute("forwarded", "forwarded value");
    dispatcher.forward(requestWrapper, response);
```

**Here is the code of wrapper implementation:**

```
    class HideExistingRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

           private Map localattributes = new HashMap();

           public HideExistingRequestWrapper (HttpServletRequest orignialRequest) {
                  super(orignialRequest);
           }

           public Object getAttribute(java.lang.String name) { 
                 return localattributes.get(name);
           }

           public Object setAttribute(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String value) { 
                 return localattributes.put(name, value);
           }

    }
```

Comment: After finishing processing in a servlet, I want to send a xml string to a jsp page. I think only redirect will work because I 've to send it to a new domain(or can we send via post in a redirect). My question is how can  I send it using Post.

Comment: Yes, if it is not within server, then it has to redirect only.

Comment: Can't there be post in redirect? Why?

Comment: Instead of hiding there is a method called removeAttribute() you can use that.

Comment: Should not do remove() incase you want the attribute after forward() returns.

Comment: forward does not return back to the original jsp page.

Comment: request.setAtribute("a", "valueA");
requestWrapper.setAtribute("forwarded", "forwarded value");
dispatcher.forward(requestWrapper, response);
request.getAtribute("a");

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ServletRequest.removeAttribute(name of your old attribute)
ServletRequest.setAttribute(name , value)
```

After setting the attributes, get the **RequestDispatcher** using

```
getRequestDispatcher(url)
```

and then use **forward()** method

Comment: @ChandraShekhar: I will try it and let you know.

Comment: :I want to remove the parametrsof the current request. Will remove attribute remove the parameters as well? Are parameters and attributes the same.

Comment: @Ashwin parameters are setted in the web.xml file, I don't think they can be removed. Well I am not sure. By the way why you want to remove the parameters?

Comment: Because I don't want to forward the parameters. I want to add new parameters and then forward. the old parameters should not be there When forwarding, by default the old parameters are also forwarded along right?

Comment: @Ashwin you can do the same with the help of attributes, why are you trying to do that using parameters. Moreover, attributes are designed to solve these situations.

Comment: okay let me ask you a question. When forwarding, by default, are the old parameters are also forwarded ?

Comment: @Ashwin No i think, you can see this http://www.xyzws.com/Servletfaq/what-is-the-difference-between-the-request-attribute-and-request-parameter/1 to be more clear

Comment: Then how to forward parameters?